# call fragment issue in button onclick

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I create a fragment extend class to call layout as following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date_time_label"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textSize="32dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"

        android:text="time_label"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/last_view_time"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/date_time_label"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/date_time_label"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="32dp"

        />

</LinearLayout>



package com.appnetics;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;



import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;




/**
 * DateTime
 */
public class details extends Fragment {
    private static String getDateTimeString(Date time) {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss")
            .format(time);
    }

    private final String time = getDateTimeString(new Date());

    /** @see android.app.Fragment#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater, android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle) */
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
        LayoutInflater inflater,
        ViewGroup container,
        Bundle b)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.details,
            container,
            false);  //!!! this is important

        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.last_view_time))
            .setText(time);

        return view;
    }
}
```

now to use it I create layout like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_showdetails"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="110dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
        android:text="Show Details" />

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
     android:id="@+id/my_parent_layout"
    >
    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

on the click event of the button I say

```
setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                        details fragment = new details();
                        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.my_parent_layout, fragment);
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();


            }
        });
```

but it raise error 
**The method getFragmentManager() is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}**

any idea how to solve that

Comment: `getApplicationContext().getFragmentManager();`

Comment: give error The method getFragmentManager() is undefined for the type Context

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if call activity from fragment then code below or call fragment to fragment then simply replace the code instead of startactivity onclick method

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_start, container, false);

        Button button1 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.StartButton);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),testing.class));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seems to be working with API 21. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Declare and set the fragmentManager as final, before  the listener definition.

```
final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

<your listener declaration>
```

you should be able to use it in the listener.

Comment: I tried but it give error The method getFragmentManager() is undefined for the type TestfragementActivity

Comment: What is your android target?  `getFragmentManager()` is available since 3.0. :::: Otherwise you should use `getSupportFragmentManager()`

Comment: I used it but it give the error The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type TestfragementActivity , I target 2.2

Comment: I guess this is obvious, but did you extend your activity from FragmenActivity, didn't you? (If you extended from Activity the method will not be available) :::: It is not easy to 'debug' your code since you did not post it.

Answer (score 1):

Below code works

```
    Button publishButton =(Button)                                                                                                  
                          fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.publishButton);
    publishButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
              publish();
           }
      });
```