# Cannot resolve the method findViewById (int) in a class

Tags: android

I have a fragment Activity Bhawan_page1 and I want to call another activity on button click but I am getting two errors 
1. Cannot resolve method 'findViewById(int)'
2. Cannot resolve constructor 'Intent(anonymous android.view.View.OnClickListener, java.lang.Class)'

Here is the code of the Activity

```
package in.ahmedraza.journey;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

import in.ahmedraza.material_tab.ObservableScrollView;
import in.ahmedraza.material_tab.ScrollUtils;
import in.ahmedraza.material_tab.Scrollable;

public class Bhawan_page1 extends FlexibleSpaceWithImageBaseFragment<ObservableScrollView> {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bhawan_page1, container, false);

        final ObservableScrollView scrollView = (ObservableScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.scroll);
        // TouchInterceptionViewGroup should be a parent view other than ViewPager.
        // This is a workaround for the issue #117:
        // https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView/issues/117
        scrollView.setTouchInterceptionViewGroup((ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_root));

        // Scroll to the specified offset after layout
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        if (args != null && args.containsKey(ARG_SCROLL_Y)) {
            final int scrollY = args.getInt(ARG_SCROLL_Y, 0);
            ScrollUtils.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(scrollView, new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    scrollView.scrollTo(0, scrollY);
                }
            });
            updateFlexibleSpace(scrollY, view);
        } else {
            updateFlexibleSpace(0, view);
        }

        scrollView.setScrollViewCallbacks(this);

        return view;

        Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.full_story_bhawan);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, DialogMainActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateFlexibleSpace(int scrollY) {
        // Sometimes scrollable.getCurrentScrollY() and the real scrollY has different values.
        // As a workaround, we should call scrollVerticallyTo() to make sure that they match.
        Scrollable s = getScrollable();
        s.scrollVerticallyTo(scrollY);

        // If scrollable.getCurrentScrollY() and the real scrollY has the same values,
        // calling scrollVerticallyTo() won't invoke scroll (or onScrollChanged()), so we call it here.
        // Calling this twice is not a problem as long as updateFlexibleSpace(int, View) has idempotence.
        updateFlexibleSpace(scrollY, getView());
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateFlexibleSpace(int scrollY, View view) {
        ObservableScrollView scrollView = (ObservableScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.scroll);

        // Also pass this event to parent Activity
        BhawanHome parentActivity =
                (BhawanHome) getActivity();
        if (parentActivity != null) {
            parentActivity.onScrollChanged(scrollY, scrollView);
        }
    }
}
```

The code for xml file

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <in.ahmedraza.material_tab.ObservableScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/flexible_space_image_height"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:text="@string/bhawan_story" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/full_story_bhawan"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="Complete Story"
                android:onClick="true"
                android:padding="@color/white"
                android:background="@color/red"
                android:gravity="center"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </in.ahmedraza.material_tab.ObservableScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: checkout this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813008/call-fragment-issue-in-button-onclick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fragments does not have findViewById method. Single invoke of this method need to be fixed from

```
Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.full_story_bhawan);
```

to

```
Button btn1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.full_story_bhawan);
```

Second thing. Dont write code after return statemant. Its never gonna be executed.
Move return of `onCreateView` after setting `onClickListener`.

Lastly the onClickListener.
Change this:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, DialogMainActivity.class);
```

to

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), DialogMainActivity.class);
```

first parameter of Intent constructor is context. `this` in you code refer to anonymous `onClickListener` not to any kind of context so it needs to be fixed.
Hope it will solve your problem.

Edit:

```
android:padding="@color/white"
```

This is never gonna work :P Change it to proper dimension value.

Comment: I am now getting an error cannot resolve getActivity() method

Comment: Its little strange, but if it happened try replacing `getActivity` with `FlexibleSpaceWithImageBaseFragment.this.getActivity()`

Comment: Adding  FlexibleSpaceWithImageBaseFragment.this.getActivity()   I am getting another error saying not an enclosing class.

Comment: Oh sorry, I wrote wrong type. `Bhawan_page1.this.getActivity()` should fix it if error is on this onClickListener

Comment: Though the issue is resolved but I'm getting a runtime error  - Binary XML file line #34: Error inflating class Button. The xml file is already there is there any mistake in the xml file